# Socket.io 'on' is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Ok, so I'm trying to learn socket.io and I get this error:

> io.socket.on('connection', function (socket) 
>   TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

heres my code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer()
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , path = require('path')
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);


// all environments
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

io.socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I know its going to be something rather obvious.

Comment: What error? `.on` should not return anything. It is simply registering an event listener.

Comment: sorry, I just realized I forgot to copy the whole error. I'll edit it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be `io.sockets.on` ("sockets" instead of "socket"):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Eff

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code is no longer working.
Here is something I made to deal with socket.io and a http server.

```
var app = require('http'),
    io = require('socket.io');

var handler = function(req, res) { /* your handler function*/ };
var server = app.createServer(handler).listen( 8000 );
var ios = io.listen(server);

ios.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.emit('message', {'message': 'hello world'});
});
```